# Dynamically get URL with anchors using JS/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, anchor, window.location

I have a website that based on anchors.

For ex. the default URL is `domain.com`.

Another section of this website has the URL `domain.com/#section1`.

One more section has the URL `domain.com/#section2`.

When I tried to get the full URL of webiste I used

> window.location.href

but when I scroll down my page and the URL changed to `domain.com/#section1` my `window.location.href` didn't change.

My JS:

```
$anchor = window.location.hash;

    if($anchor == "#kraftwerk-82"){
        $(".starting-logo.default-logo").attr("src","/logo_main.png");
        $(".starting-logo.default-logo").attr("srcset","/logo_main.png 1x, /retina_logo.png 2x");
    }else{
        $(".starting-logo.default-logo").attr("src","/logo_main_white.png");
        $(".starting-logo.default-logo").attr("srcset","/logo_main_white.png 1x, /retina_logo_white.png 2x");
    }
```

How can I dynamically get the URL with right anchor using JS?

Comment: are you using jQuery??

Comment: Yes. I'm using it for my if statement after I got the right href.

Comment: Where is your anchor change function? When you scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.location.hash` for get only the hash tag:

```
yourHash = window.location.hash.substring(1)
```

**UPDATE**

```
if(window.location.hash){
    console.log(window.location.href + window.location.hash);
}else{
    console.log(window.location.href);
}
```

**UPDATE II**

When you scroll you need to change the hash. example:

```
var anchor_top = $('a[href="#kraftwerk-82"]').offset().top;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > anchor_top ) {
        window.location.hash = '#kraftwerk-82';
    }
});
```

And on function called you can check what is the hash now:

```
Function track(){
    $anchor = window.location.hash;
    if($anchor == "#kraftwerk-82"){
        $(".starting-logo.default-logo").attr("src","/logo_main.png");
        $(".starting-logo.default-logo").attr("srcset","/logo_main.png 1x, /retina_logo.png 2x");
    }else{
        $(".starting-logo.default-logo").attr("src","/logo_main_white.png");
        $(".starting-logo.default-logo").attr("srcset","/logo_main_white.png 1x, /retina_logo_white.png 2x");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't clear.
I mean I want to have a function that will dynamically show me the full URL of my website when I'm scrolling down.
For ex. I made a `console.log` and got - `domain.com`.
When I scroll down to another section my `console.log` should return me `domain.com/#section1` dynamically.

Comment: You can detect if hash tag exist and make your url. Try update

Comment: When I'm scrolling down `console.log` still shows the first anchor. It doesn't dynamically shows other anchors...

Comment: Please past your javascript what you try in your issue post.

Comment: I added my JS code. So I want to change logo color on the #kraftwerk-82 anchor but other anchors should have default color.